# In JavaScript, how would I create an array of numbers from 0 to 7, where the index of x is 7?

Tags: javascript, math, logic

I need a piece of code that basically lets me specify the length of the array (y) and the highest index point (x), and returns an array where the index of x is equal to y.

For instance:
y = 7
x = 3

0, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Ultimately this is producing a list of numbers from 0 to 7, and then rearranging those numbers so that the largest number is 3rd in the list.

Comment: Is this for homework?

Comment: @JPRichardson it certainly seems to show little to no specificity to javascript and no familiarity with the language either.

Comment: Haha, it is not. I'm creating a book in CSS and JavaScript. This array is used to give each page in the book its z-index. So, when you turn to page 3, it has the highest z-index (of 7, for example) - and therefore it is on top, just like a real book.

Comment: However I since refactored my code as I came up with a better solution. Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array easily using the `[]` syntax:

```
[] // An empty array
```

You can add items to an array using push:

```
myArray.push(someValue);
```

So, how could you create an array from 0 to y, using a `for` loop? If you can't figure it out, mouse over the below rectangle:

> ```
> var arr = [];
> for(var i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
>     arr.push(i);
> }
> ```

Okay, you have your array, now all you need to do is move the last element to the `x`th position. You can do this using the very versatile [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), check out the documentation.

Now check your answer:

> ```
> arr.splice(x, 0, arr.pop());
> ```

`arr` is now the result you needed.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSUFx/1/).

Comment: Why are you adding that one to the end?

Comment: Well, at least that means *I'm* not going crazy :P

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for helping me understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var y = 7,
    x = 3,
    arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < y + 1; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}

arr.splice(x - 1, 0, arr.pop()); 

arr; // 0,1,7,2,3,4,5,6
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEa9a/).

Comment: If the array length is supposed to be 7, why are there 8 values?

Comment: @Purmou - because the original question was worded poorly. This is the requested output...

Comment: Count the `0`. @nnnnnn: Yeah, I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another (and understandable, albeit a bit lengthier than others' answers):

```
var x = 3,
    y = 7;
    arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<y+1;i++){
    if(i == x - 1){
        arr[i] = y;  
    } else if(i >= x){
        arr[i] = i - 1;   
    } else {
        arr[i] = i;   
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/CPkTs/).

During the `for loop`, when `i` is equal to `x - 1` (Javascript has 0-based indexing), it will set `arr[i]` equal to `y`. If `i` is greater than or equal to `x`, it will set `arr[i]` to `i - 1` (so we're subtracting 1 from each value of the array after the one we set to `y`). The last `else` covers the array's values before we get stuff complicated (so 0 and 1).

Answer (score 0):

> I need a piece of code that basically lets me specify the length of the array (y) and the highest index point (x), and returns an array where the index of x is equal to y.

The length of the array is not y, it is y+1 if you want the first element to have the value 0. Note also that JavaScript array indexes are 0-based, so the third array position has index 2, or x-1.

The following matches your sample input/output of 7,3 => 0,1,7,2,3,4,5,6

```
function makeStrangeArray(y, x) {
   var a = [],
       i;
   for(i = 0; i < y; i++) {
      if(i===x-1)
         a.push(y);
      a.push(i);
   }
   return a;
}

alert(makeStrangeArray(7,3)); // 0,1,7,2,3,4,5,6
```